# how to generate a "serie" of numbers based on a value:

Tags: google-sheets

I am stuck with a little problem.

i would like to auto-generate a Serie of numbers(is this the right description?):
for example:
The input/value in A1 is 5
the OUTPUT in B1 should now be 1
in
in cell B2 - 2,
B3 - 3,
B4 - 4,
B5 - 5,
B6 - 1, (STARTING at one again)
B7 - 2
. . . and so on until end of range

if I then change the value in A1 to 7 for example it should now "count" from 1 to 7 and repeat until the end of the range again.

any hints available would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:B),1,0),A1)+1)
```

this is creating an array of numbers from 0 to however many rows there are on the sheet, then taking the modulus of each number using the value of A1 as a divisor.

MOD() means "what's the remainder after dividing by [n]?"  where N in your example case is 6 or 7 or whatever.

Comment: damm it. thats a gentle solution. thank you very much